# format-string + ret2libc (or format string only)?

Tags: ghidra, gdb, exploit

I found that we have a format-string bug with in argument 7. I found a function containing system(`/bin/sh`)). So I'm not saying stupidity I have to mess with a format-string and a `ret2libc` (correct me if I'm wrong). I don't know how to exploit it, can you help me?

*Images: Ghidra and GDB*

[image: system function]

[image: entry function]

[image: all functions on gdb]